# как отправить письмо на symfony спомощью swift mailer

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony

Я хочу отправить письмо с локольного сервера используя swiftmailer и gmail на symfony.
Вот фрагменты кода

```js
/src/MailerBundle/controller/defaultController

<?php

namespace MailerBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $Request = $this->getRequest();
        if($Request->getMethod()=="POST") {
            $name = $Request->get('name');
            $email = $Request->get('email');
            $subject =$Request->get('subject');
            $message = $Request->get('message');
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->setFrom($email)
                ->setTo('any@whatever.com')
                ->setBody('ExampleBundle:Default:mail.html.twig', 'text/html');

# Send the message
            $this->get('mailer')
                ->send($message);
        }
        return $this->render('MailerBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

```css
//config_dev.yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: %dev_mailer_transport%
    host:      %dev_mailer_host%
    username:  %dev_mailer_user%
    password:  %dev_mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

```html
//parameters.yml

# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: 3rw23ewre343ewrew3434rwrew34343wre
# Mail setup for development environment
dev_mailer_transport: gmail
dev_mailer_host: null
dev_mailer_user: example@gmail.com
dev_mailer_password: password

# Mail setup for production environment
prod_mailer_transport: smtp
prod_mailer_host: localhost
prod_mailer_user: null
prod_mailer_password: null
```

но как то не получается, перепрововал все методы. Помогите

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в двухфакторной авторизации у вас на учетной записи *gmail*. В этом случае придется [получить](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)  отдельный пароль для приложения и использовать его в 
параметре *mailer_password*.

Также книга рецептов *symfony* [рекомендует](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html) посмотреть [справку](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) по доступам.